# Difference between [detach] and [set offline and drop database]

Tags: sql-server

MSDN says *"If the database or any one of its files is offline when it is dropped, the disk files are not deleted"*. So if I first set database offline and then drop it

```
alter database newbase set offline
drop database newbase
```

The database files will remain on the disk and then they can be attached again.
So, what is the difference, if I detach instead

```
exec sp_detach_db @dbname='newbase'
```

Comment: https://dallasdbas.com/database_delete_detach_offline/

Answer (score 1):

See [Dropping an Offline Database in SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/02/dropping-offline-database-sql-server/) by Kendra Little. In summary, the offline/drop behaviour is by design, and although the 2 approaches are technically different (different processes and different actions logged) the nett effect is the same.

Comment: would you mind providing more information about differences please?